# AngularJS - Auto $pristine and $error styles for form fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can a simple directive be used to apply styles to form fields when they are $error and !$pristine?

For example, instead of writing a lengthy:

```
<div 
   ng-class="{'has-error':(myform.myField.$error && !myform.myField.$pristine) === true}">
   <!-- myField is inside the div -->
```

Can I just write something like:

```
<div err-pris-cls="'has-error', myField">
```

Are directives the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a new directive which will basically add class or remove it, I'd use `ng-class` directive itself, but will move code from html to controller which will also make sense to have testable code. That `isValid` controller function can be easily testable.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': isValid(myform.myField)">
```

**Code**

```
$scope.isValid = function(field){
   return (field.$error && !field.$pristine) === true;
}
```

Comment: I guess I tend to overthink things.